# Using TASK class in VB.NET async

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, async-await

This is my first post here, so i hope to be very explicit about my problem.

Currently i'm working with a database, and at some point, i'm having some problems with the latency because of the data amont.

What i want is, when i press a button in the MainForm to call separate Task that takes a method that populates a comboBox in another form, and then display that form.

Here is the code :

```
Private Sub PopulateCmb()
    For Each value As Integer In servRefrence.PopulateID_Masini
        Form_Insert.ComboBox1.Items.Add(value)
    Next
    <<This is taking 3-4 seconds>>
End Sub

Private Async Sub BtnInsert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnInsert.Click

    Dim task As Task = New Task(New Action(AddressOf PopulateCmb))
    task.Start()
    LblInfo.Text = "Please Wait"
    Await task

    LblInfo.Text = "Idle"
    Form_Insert.Show()

End Sub
```

This method : servRefrence.PopulateID_Masini is returning a list of integers that comes from the webserver...

The problem with this code is that when the task is finished, the combobox within the Form_Insert comes back empty!

What am i missing??...I think is maybe because you cannot make use of a task within the mainForm(for ex.), and try to "modify" some data in a second form...but i'm not sure...

==I am using Visual Studio 2012==  Template : Visual Basic

Please help!

Thank You!!!

Comment: [You shouldn't ever use the `Task` constructor](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that you are populating the comboBox in non-UI thread. I guess that latency is caused by service call, so you should populate combobox after task await in UI thread.

```
Dim task = Task.Factory.StartNew(Of List(Of Integer))(
           Function() As List(Of Integer)
                 Return servRefrence.PopulateID_Masini
           End Function)

Dim result = Await task

For Each value As Integer In result
    Form_Insert.ComboBox1.Items.Add(value)
Next
```

Comment: Yes. It would be even better to [use `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).